# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'get_isLoading': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, ssrs-2008

I am trying to print my report viewer report using the code below and I am getting a error that Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'get_isLoading': object is null or undefined.  Any ideas?

```
<script language="javascript">
        function PrintReport() {
        var viewerReference = $find("ReportViewer1");

        var stillonLoadState = viewerReference.get_isLoading();

        if (!stillonLoadState) {
            var reportArea = viewerReference.get_reportAreaContentType();
            if (reportArea == Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportAreaContent.ReportPage) {
                $find("ReportViewer1").invokePrintDialog();
            }
        }
    } 
 </script>
```

Comment: `$find("ReportViewer1");` - that failed to find the element

Comment: What could I change it to if that it is what my reportviewer is called ReportViewer1?

Answer (score 0):

ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewer1 is the name of the control